# Issue loading data into a dropdown via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, dropdown

Encountering an issue loading a dropdown dynamically using JQuery AJAX.
The php is returning a valid JSON response. But when I attempt to load the data, I'm getting back either undefined, [object Object] or a single option with all my values comma separated. Nothing I've tried yields the correct answer.

This is the AJAX code block:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url:"data/getdata_codes.php",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
      alert("Success section");
      alert(data);
      $.each(data,function(key,value) <--Fails here
      {
        alert(key);
        alert(value);
        var option="<option value="+key+">"+value+"</option>";
        alert(option);
        $(option).appendTo('#myList');
      });
 },
 error: function(xhr) {
    alert("An error occured: "+ xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
 }
```

});

This is the JSON which is returned from the PHP, it validates.

```
{"data":[[{"0":"-1","CODE":"-1"}],
[{"0":"0","CODE":"0"}],
[{"0":"12","CODE":"12"}],
[{"0":"213","CODE":"213"}],
[{"0":"357","CODE":"357"}],
[{"0":"364","CODE":"364"}],
[{"0":"501","CODE":"501"}],
[{"0":"661","CODE":"661"}]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your array is filled with arrays with 1 object. That makes it overly complicated.

Try something like this:

```
$(data.data).each(function(index, element) <- I guess your data variable also has a data attribute?
      {
        var array = element;
        var objectInArray = array[0];

        var key = objectInArray.0;
        var value = objectInArray.CODE;
        alert(key);
        alert(value);
        var option="<option value="+key+">"+value+"</option>";
        alert(option);
        $(option).appendTo('#myList');
      });
```